# $.ajax( type: “POST” POST method to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to use the POST method in jQuery to send mobile to a php file called `save.php`. So this is the code in the html page:

```
<script>
            function saveit(userid){

                var number = userid;
                number = number.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");

                var transaction = sendNumber(number);

                if(transaction === '0'){
                    //alert("Transaction Successfull");
                    console.log('Success');
                }else{
                    console.log('Failed');
                }


                userid=userid;
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "./ajax/save.php",
                  data: { userid: userid },
                  beforeSend: function (  ) {

                  }
                }).done(function ( data ) {
                    alert("Vielen Dank, Sie wurden erfolgreich registriert");
                    window.history.back();

                    if( console && console.log ) {
                    console.log("Sample of data:", data);
                  }
                });
                return false;
            }
</script>
```

My question is now, what should I write in `save.php` to see all the numbers?

Comment: <?php echo $_POST['userid']; ?>

Comment: `print_r($_POST['userid']);` in `save.php`

Comment: <?php var_dump($_POST); ?>

Answer (score -1):

You will need a server running, are you doing this on your own computer via xampp or similar, or do you have a hosting provider ?

```html
<?php echo $_POST['userid']; ?>
```

Comment: i have a hosting provider